# Is there someone defending "aristotelic" existence conditions of universals besides (maybe) Aristotle?

Tags: ontology

I read quite regularly about Aristotle holding (more or less) the following position: Universals (properties, kinds, ...) exist iff (or: when and only when) they are instantiated. So for example "man (kind)" exists now iff there are now men. Or: The property of illness exists now iff something/someone is now ill. (The last one is maybe Aristotle's example in the *Categories* (*14a* or something)) 
(Aristotle probably didnt really hold that exact position, but anyway.)

So, my question: Do you know another philosopher besides Aristotle who holds that universals exist now iff they are now instantiated?

Comment: If memory serves, I believe Acquinas was very much in line with Aristotle on this topic.